# Getting keypress on a Form in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to make a image viewer in powershell using some windows forms libraries, I can already store the images location inside an array, but now I want it to detect the keys `Right` and `Left` to change between the locations inside the array

Here is the code I'm using:

```
param(
[parameter (Mandatory=$false, position=0, ParameterSetName='url')]
[string]$url = ''
)
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
Function Load-Images{
    param (
        [parameter (Mandatory=$true, position=0, ParameterSetName='path')]
        $path
    )

    $screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens
    $form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form

    $form.Text = "Image Viewer"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($screen.WorkingArea[0].Width, $screen.WorkingArea[0].Height)
    
    $pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    $pictureBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($screen.WorkingArea[0].Width, $screen.WorkingArea[0].Height)
    
   
    $pictureBox.Image = $path
    $pictureBox.SizeMode = 'Zoom'
    $pictureBox.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'

    $form.controls.add($pictureBox)
    $form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )

    $form.ShowDialog()
    $img.dispose()
}

if(!$url) {
    $dir = Get-Location

    $Files = @(Get-ChildItem "$($dir.Path)\*" -Include *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)
    $maxSize = $Files.Length
    Write-Output $maxSize
    Write-Output $Files.Fullname
    $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile((Get-Item $Files.Fullname[0]))
    Load-Images -path $img

}
```

Comment: Why? Why not just put navigation buttons on the form? It's more direct, no other coding gymnastics required. Anyway, what did you search for? [powershell WinForm keypress](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+winform+keypress&form=ANNTH1&refig=11041cac46d74b2c9add2fd08e8ffd76&sp=-1&pq=powershell+winform+keypress&sc=0-27&qs=n&sk=&cvid=11041cac46d74b2c9add2fd08e8ffd76) BTW, I'm all for learning/experimenting, but why to this, when Windows OS already provides one and many are downloadable. Yet, do research on `.KeyPreview` and how to leverage it.

Comment: Remember, running GUI in PowerShell does not preclude you from spending the needed time fully understanding UX/UI elements., to limit/avoid confusion, mistakes, errors, etc., as you go down this use case. Three are literally tons of examples of this on SO (use the SO search box above) and all over the web via your favorite search engine.

Comment: Yep, i know i could use a button, but I wanted to just only show the image (And found it a little bit challenging(?), I was just tinkering with powershell and that stuff). 
About the WinForm Keypress, I was using the docs for C# and then I "adapted" them by just thinking how they would work on powershell, sorry about that.
About why an image viewer. That was just for fun, nothing special really like you said for learning/experimenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. What you are after is not specific to PowerShell at all. It's a [UX/UI](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=winform%20ux%2Fui%20events%20keypress) design/property/event item.

For Example, here is one showing adding and using the property/event setting to watch for defined keypresses. Just run the function, call the function, and hit 'Enter' or 'Esc', or click 'OK' to fire those events.

```
function Start-CreateForm 
{ 
 
    #Import Assemblies 
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms,
                           System.Drawing
 
    $Form1                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $OKButton               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState 
    $Label1                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $textBox1               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $Field1 = ""
 
    # Check for ENTER and ESC presses
    $Form1.KeyPreview = $True
    $Form1.Add_KeyDown({if ($PSItem.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
        # if enter, perform click
        $OKButton.PerformClick()
        }
    })
    $Form1.Add_KeyDown({if ($PSItem.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
        # if escape, exit
        $Form1.Close()
        }
    })
 
    # The action on the button
    $handler_OK_Button_Click= 
    { 
        $Field1 = $textBox1.Text
        $Field1
     
        # Returns a message of no data
        if ($Field1 -eq "") {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You didn't enter anything!", "Data")}
     
        # Returns what they types. You could add your code here
        else {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Field1, "Data")}  
    }
 
    $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection= 
    {
    $Form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState 
    }
 
 
    # Form Code 
    $Form1.Name = "Data_Form"
    $Form1.Text = "Data Form" 
    $Form1.MaximizeBox = $false #lock form
    $Form1.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
    # None,FixedDialog,FixedSingle,FixedToolWindow,Sizable,SizableToolWindow
 
    # Icon
    $Form1.Icon = [Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Command powershell).Path)
    # $NotifyIcon.Icon = [Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Get-Command powershell).Path)
 
    $Form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
    $Form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"# moves form to center of screen
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 300 # sets X
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 150 # sets Y
    $Form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
 
    $OKButton.Name = "OK_Button" 
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 45
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
 
    $OKButton.Size = $System_Drawing_Size 
    $OKButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 30 
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 113
 
    $OKButton.Location = $System_Drawing_Point 
    $OKButton.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
    $OKButton.add_Click($handler_OK_Button_Click)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($OKButton)
 
    $InitialFormWindowState = $Form1.WindowState 
    $Form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection) 
 
    $Label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
    $Label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
    $Label1.Text = "Enter data here:"
    $Form1.Controls.Add($Label1)
  
    $textBox1.TabIndex = 0 # Places cursor in field
    $textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
    $textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
    $Form1.Controls.Add($textBox1)
    $Form1.Topmost = $True # Moves form to top and stays on top
    $Form1.Add_Shown({$textBox1.Select()})
 
    # Show Form 
    $Form1.ShowDialog()
}
```

For your use case, you just have to use the needed keyboard specifics.